# Unresolved Reference for function in Python

Tags: python

I'm running Python 3.9 in Pycharm. I am trying to run this code where I create a function that does addition. I am getting an error that says unresolved reference and for some reason, it is telling me that `add` is not defined. I've tried rearranging the order of functions to see if that would change anything and it did not.

[image: Python code]

Comment: Try `self.add`.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, and terminal output as **TEXT**

Comment: Also, since you seem to be not using `self` anywhere, you might want to read this and understand what's it for when creating and using classes: [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096552/2745495). You shouldn't need that `global first, second, total` in there.

Comment: The answer by Suyog Shimp is correct. I would say that defining the add function outside the class would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You may miss `@staticmethod` decorator at top of the method `add`, Also you must call the method by `self` as `self.add(x, y)`

like -

```
@staticmethod
def add(x, y):
   ...
```

Otherwise, you can add `self` as the first parameter

```
def add(self, x, y):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah You'll get an error as add is not defined, you need to change it to: Addition.add

Answer (score 0):

`add` is a function and not a method looking from your screenshot, it has to be a member of the class for the class to know that `add` is present. There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

```
@staticmenthod
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

or

```
def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y
```

or

```
@classmethod
def add(cls, x, y):
    return x + y
```

then on `line 42` from your screenshot, you will do

```
total = self.add(first, second)
```

But I am looking at your class and I am worried on why you are using globals, and not class variables or instance variables?

and since `process` calls `add`, and add has no link with any attribute of the class, it will be ideal to make `add` either a static method or take it out of the class to a make it a function on it's own.

Look into OOP, check out this link https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/